# How to change tooltip text and styles in html5 forms?

Tags: css, html

How change tooltip text and styles in html5 forms?
[example](http://jsfiddle.net/9GM68/)

```
<form action='mail.php'>
Enter email: <input name='email' type='email' value='not email' />
<input type='submit' value='send' />
</form>
```

Comment: Can you possibly be more precise? I'm having a hard time understanding what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot use HTML5 nor CSS to directly change the look & feel of the tooltips of elements.

This is because tooltips are part of the HTML5 specification that each browser renders on it's own way, so there is no specificaton about how to change it's styles.

However, you can create your own tooltips using hidden divs associated to your elements.

Just show then on mouse over and give them the styles you want.

Even if you are enough good with JS and CSS you can do them show up with a fade effect and after a brief delay since the on mouse enter event.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zosAl)

```
<form action='mail.php'>
Enter email: <input name='email' type='email' placeholder='not email' />
<input type='submit' value='send' class="btn"/>
</form>


input {
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  border: 2px solid #ececec;
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fafafa;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.btn {
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height:30px;
  width: 110px;
  color: #fff;
  background: green;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.btn:hover {
  position: relative;
  top:2px;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {color:#c0392b; font-size:14px;}
::-moz-placeholder          {color:#c0392b; font-size:14px;}/* Firefox 19+ */
:-moz-placeholder           {color:#c0392b; font-size:14px;}/* Firefox 18- */
:-ms-input-placeholder      {color:#c0392b; font-size:14px;}
:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: transparent}
:focus::-moz-placeholder          {color: transparent}
:focus:-moz-placeholder           {color: transparent}
:focus:-ms-input-placeholder      {color: transparent}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct, you cannot change styles of standard tooltips, but you can use this polifill (https://github.com/dsheiko/HTML5-Form-Shim) while having on the form element attribute data-custom-validation. This will make browser treating your form as intended by its HTML5 markup, but with custom tooltips on submit. You can find here details:
http://dsheiko.com/weblog/making-use-of-html5-form